# Android: перенос изображения в специальное поле

Tags: android, eclipse

В активности есть ImageButton. По нажатию на них, необходимо, чтобы эти картинки появлялись в специально отведенном для этого поле. Картинки в нем появляются в том порядке, в каком нажали на их оригиналы. По нажатию на картинку в поле, оно исчезает. Какую структуру и как лучше использовать для создания такого поля? Только учусь и использую для создания приложения eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

ImageView использовать. Для каждого изображения. Добавляйте новый ImageView  в LinearLayout, и устанавливайте ему `imageView.setImageDrawable(imageButton.getDrawable());`
когда кликаете по imageButton. Когда кликаете по imageView, просто удаляете его из парента.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужен контейнер, например LinearLayout. Можно зарание добавить его в xml файл разметки:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/conteiner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

2. Далее в коде можно добавлять изображения в контейнер, например по onClick

   ```
   //находим контейнер
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.conteiner);

   //создаем виджет
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
   imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

   //добавляем виджет в контейнер
   layout.addView(imageView);
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло. Если Вам не сложно, можете сказать еще, как сделать так, чтобы добавлялись изображения в контейнер сверху вниз? Использовала и горизонтальную, и вертикальную LinearLayout, не помогло.